# Invalid JSON in Play 2 WS post request

Tags: json, maven, playframework-2.0

My testing code is like this

```
@Test
public void testloginController() throws InterruptedException {
    running(testServer(9000), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JsonNode jsonBody = Json.toJson(myObject);
            WSRequestHolder requestBuilder = WS.url("requestURL").setContentType("application/json");

            WSRequestHolder requestHolder = requestBuilder.setTimeout(80000);
            Promise<WS.Response> promiseOfResult = requestHolder.post(jsonBody);
            WS.Response response = promiseOfResult.get();
            JsonNode jsonResponse = response.asJson();
        }
    });
}
```

**Case 1:** If I use "play test" command then this code is running properly.

**Case 2** If I use "mvn test" then I got the following error "Bad Request occured Invalid Json" 
**But if application server is running separately in test execution time then it is working properly**